# custom prompt for system encryption password entry on startup

Tags: arch-linux, configuration, encryption, disk-encryption, dm-crypt

I have full disk encryption on my arch linux laptop. When i power on the machine it prompts me for my disk password. My system is encrypted by following the LVM on luks archwiki page.
the prompt says something like "a password is required for the cryptlvm volume" i would like to change this to feature some imformation about the system like the owner and an address to return it to if lost. So far i have just tried to look at the arch wiki and search to see if anyone else had asked anything similar but i cannot seem to find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that that you can make a custom initramfs module with mkinitcpio that prints out such information. Ensure you follow this correctly, otherwise your kernel will panic. To do so, you can create  files under:

- /usr/lib/initcpio/hooks/MODULENAME
- /usr/lib/initcpio/install/MODULENAME

**/usr/lib/initcpio/install/MODULENAME** 
This is a bash script that helps build the module when you regenerate initramfs with mkinitcpio. It must have build() and help() functions. The build function calls an add_runscript command which adds our runtime bash file of the same name under: /usr/lib/initcpio/hooks/MODULENAME.

```bash
build() {

    add_runscript
}
```

**/usr/lib/initcpio/hooks/MODULENAME** 
This is a bash script that is run when initramfs is loaded.
Any commands you would like to be run must be in a function called run_hook()

```bash
run_hook() {
    # note this environment is limited as our drive is encrypted
    # only core system commands will be available 
    # it is possible to add more commands to the initramfs environment
    echo "hello!!"
}
```

**Add hook to mkinitcpio.conf** 
Now we add the hook to the array in our mkinitcpio configuration file located at /etc/mkinitcpio.conf

```bash
# we put in the custom hook
# we put it before our encrypt hook!!
# so it shows before our password prompt
HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf kms keyboard MODULENAME encrypt lvm2 keymap consolefont block filesystems fsck)
```

**Regenerate mkinitcpio** 
finally we can regenerate our initramfs so that this module can loaded on next boot.

```bash
$~ sudo mkinitcpio -p linux
```

Check the output for any errors before rebooting to check -- and pray for no kernel panic!